# Problem with registration path

Tags: 7, users

I'm trying to use Profile2 and Profile2 Registration Path to create 3 different profiles but when i register a new user I don't see the registration page of the profile but the drupal's default registration forms...where i wrong? How should i do?

Comment: Have you installed Profile2 module( https://drupal.org/project/profile2 ) ?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the two modules..

Comment: I guess users need to go to /user page to edit their profiles. You can add an edit link in the menu

Comment: Yes, i have done this. But this is my problem: during the registration, drupal gives user the default registration form and just only after his login he can modify his profile with my correct and personalized form. How can i use my personalized registration form directly from the registration of the new user? I try with this option "Show on all user account registration forms" but in my case, user must choose from three different profiles and using this option, drupal returns to me, all three kind of forms with all their fields in the same page.

Comment: User must choose from three different kind of profile: 
profile A
profile B
profile C

After that i'd want that drupal gives him the corresponding profile registration (any of them have different fields from the others).
But all this process during the registration, not after the first login!

Profile2 registration path offers me this possibility?

I hope to be clear in my explanations...

Comment: I've hardly used it. Let me guess again. After login, you should redirect the user to profile page using Rules module etc in case relevant fields are not filled up. Also see this related post: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40272/force-existing-users-to-complete-profile-after-adding-required-fields